# Xinput Gamepad not detected

Tags: 19.10, xinput, gamepad

I bought a Gamesir T4 gamepad that has Xinput support. In windows, it is recognized as a Xbox One Controller and works normally. But in Ubuntu 19.10 I am unable to get it working on Xinput mode. It does not show up on jstest and also on Steam. This gamepad has Dinput support, this mode it is detected, but the humble does not work.

While in Xinput mode, when I run `lsusb` I get the following line for the gamepad, where I cannot see the device name:

```
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 2f24:0050
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Just maintain pressed the home button until the lights at the center change to this

```
00
##
##
00
```

On this mode the gamepad will be detected and work just fine, the only thing that doesn't work is the rumble

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, XInput gamepads are typically supported through the xpad kernel module. xpad maintains a list of vendor and product IDs for supported gamepads:

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/drivers/input/joystick/xpad.c#L107

If you're feeling adventurous, you could try modifying xpad to add your device to the list. It should work as long as Gamesir T4 behaves exactly like an Xbox One controller.

```
{ 0x2f24, 0x0050, "Gamesir T4", 0, XTYPE_XBOXONE },
```

Comment: I tried a lot of things but none have worked, so I decided to sell the gamepad. But out of curiosity, to try this solution, would I have to fork the kernel, recompile it and manually install it on Ubuntu??